# Zero padding for LSTM input

Tags: lstm, rnn, word-embeddings

I am building a text-generation model. In the first layer, I am using Word2Vec embeddings. Now since the input is sentences they are variable length and I am padding them with zero. The input is basically zero padded arrays of indexes of the words which appeared. My problem is that 0 is an index of some word, so isn't padding the sequences with 0 is feeding wrong information to the model. 
PFB my code. train_x is the training input, train_y is the final word in my sentence, corpus is the entire corpus of sentences. word2idx function fetches index for the word it is passed, max_sentence_len is the max sentence length in the corpus and is used for zero-padding.

```
train_x = np.zeros([len(corpus), max_sentence_len], dtype=np.int32)
train_y = np.zeros([len(corpus)], dtype=np.int32)
for i, sentence in enumerate(corpus):
    if len(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)) > 2:
        for t, word in enumerate(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)[:-1]):
            if word in word_model.wv.vocab:
                train_x[i, t] = word2idx(word)
        train_y[i] = word2idx(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)[-1])
```

To elaborate further say the index of hi is 0 and there is 1 and my max_sentence_len is 5 so for an input hi there, my input array looks like [0,1,0,0,0] which translates to [hi, there, hi, hi, hi]. This sounds incorrect to me. Is this how it should be or is there a way to go about it.

Comment: Welcome!
It is better to add the code that receives this array. It might be a way to feed an all-zero vector for embedding of padded cells, or set -1 that is not reserved for any word which generates an all-zero embedding? May be you could add a word with index X that has an all-zero embedding? so pads with index X would be that word?

Comment: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1900 
This issue is your problem which seems not been solved yet! `'0' padding as the first word`